# Is it safe to delete MyBusiness OU after migration away from SBS?

Tags: windows, active-directory, windows-server-2012, windows-server-2012-r2

Back last year we migrated to a number of Windows Server 2012 servers from SBS.

Is it safe to delete the MyBusiness OU that was part of our old SBS setup?

Example contents of Security Group within MyBusiness OU.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It should be BUT I would disable the contents first, be it users and/or security groups. If they are still in use (we would sometimes continue to use the groups post migration) and there are issues you can easily re-enable them.

If there are no adverse affects after a number of weeks then make sure you have a good backup and go ahead and delete them.

Hope that helps,

Marcus